# adding multiple JSONArrays to JSONArray

Tags: java

i'm searching for an option to add multiple values to a JSONArray and add this into another JSONArray without creating multiple variables. For example:

```
    JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray();
    array2.add("ex1");
    array2.add("ex2");
    array2.add("ex3");
    array1.add(array2);
```

into something like:

```
    JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray();
    array1.add(new JSONArray().addAll(Arrays.asList("ex1","ex2","ex3")));
    array1.add(new JSONArray().addAll(Arrays.asList("ex4","ex5","ex6")));
```

is there a way to do this? Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using gson:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is a running code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;

public class JArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonArray array1 = new JsonArray();

        array1.addAll(getJsonArrayFromList(Arrays.asList("ex1", "ex2", "ex3")));
        array1.addAll(getJsonArrayFromList(Arrays.asList("ex4", "ex5", "ex6")));

        System.out.println("array1 = " + array1);
    }

    public static JsonArray getJsonArrayFromList(List<String> list) {
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        for (String s : list) {
            array.add(s);
        }
        return array;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
array1 = ["ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4","ex5","ex6"]
```